# Spring @Bean configuration is not working, loses it's config when autoscanned in development environment

Tags: java, spring, configuration, webclient, spring-bean

I have a configuration class to create a WebClient with some specifis SSL setup. There is another WebClient bean in the service, so I used a Qualifier annotation. Before moved this to a Configuration class, all of the setup were working and the post request was successful, but now the url and httpclient is null if I want to use this as a Bean.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sslClient")
    public WebClient webClient(DeviceConfig config, Credentials credentials, HttpClientManager httpClientManager) {
        HttpClient httpClient = httpClientManager.getHttpClient(credentials);
        return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .baseUrl(config.url)
            .build();
    }
}
```

The class where I want to use this Client looks like:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiClient {
    @Qualifier("sslClient")
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public String postRequest(String body) {
        return webClient.post()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .bodyValue(body)
            .retreive()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block()
    }

}
```

When I try to run this method, I receive an error message "unable to parse URL".

If I remove the Qualifier from the Bean, the build throws exception, so it is clearly using this WebClient and not a different one.
I tried to modify the code, to move the URL to the postRequest method, but then the SSLHandshake exception happened, because obviously the clientconnector setup was missing.
Why does the bean not have it's configured setup?

If I run the app locally, and using debug, I see the url and clientconnector is still there in the ApiClient webClient setup. But in development environment it's null for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The field is missing the `@Autowired` annotation. Use

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sslClient")
private final WebClient webClient;
```

instead of just

```java
@Qualifier("sslClient")
private final WebClient webClient;
```